# Display a sweet alert on ajax add to cart for a specific Woocommerce cart item count

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

**The Problem:**

I am trying to display a JavaScript alert when AJAX is called. But the alert only fires successfully when I refresh the page.

**Here is the start of the function which triggers the javascript IF cart items > 2:**

So if there are more than 2 items in the Woocommerce cart, run the Javascript alert...

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'trigger_popup' );
function trigger_popup() {

  global $woocommerce;
  $maximum_num_products = 2;
  $cart_num_products = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();

        if( $cart_num_products > $maximum_num_products ) {
```

**Then I am trying to display the javascript alert when ajax is called:**

I researched [Global Ajax Event Handlers](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) and I think *$.ajaxComplete* is whats needed, but it doesn't trigger the javascript. I'm also trying to set the URL Ajax JS Handler in an attempt to trigger the alert...

```
    ?>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert2@7.20.1/dist/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

                //EXECUTE FOR AJAX?
                $( document ).ajaxComplete(function(){

                //URL NEEDED FOR AJAX TO WORK?
                  url: '/?wc-ajax=add_to_cart',

                    // ALERT CODE HERE
                  swal(
                    'You added all the items!',
                    'Proceed to checkout?',
                    'success')
                    //END OF ALERT CODE

        })(jQuery);
        </script>

<?php
  }
}
```

**As FYI, This is the working version of the Javascript triggers the alert ON PAGE REFRESH, but not for AJAX:**

If there are more than 2 items in the cart, AND I refresh the page. This successfully triggers the javascript alert.

```
    ?>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert2@7.20.1/dist/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                  swal(
                    'You added all the items!',
                    'Proceed to checkout?',
                    'success')
        </script>
<?php
  }
}
```

How can I get the Javascript alert to trigger on Ajax OR check if the IF conditions have been met, each time Ajax is called?

Thanks!

Comment: well you should wrap it in a function. Look ay Ajax success or done

Comment: @epascarello Will the function I already have not run the javascript? `$( document ).ajaxComplete(function(){`

Comment: Ajax Complete adds the method to every ajax call on the page. Doubt you want to use that.

Comment: @epascarello I have tried using `.ajaxSuccess` but doesnt seem to change anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code where jQuery code will send an ajax request on "added_to_cart" delegated event. On that request php will get the cart item count and will return it to jQuery. If that count met some condition, it will display your sweet-alert message:

```
// Wordpress Ajax: Get different cart items count
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_checking_cart_items', 'checking_cart_items' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_checking_cart_items', 'checking_cart_items' );
function checking_cart_items() {
    if( isset($_POST['added']) ){
        // For 2 different cart items
        echo json_encode( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) );
    }
    die(); // To avoid server error 500
}

// The Jquery script
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_popup_script' );
function custom_popup_script() {
    ?>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert2@8.8.1/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/promise-polyfill@8.1.0/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        // The Ajax function
        $(document.body).on('added_to_cart', function() {
            console.log('event');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: wc_add_to_cart_params.ajax_url,
                data: {
                    'action': 'checking_cart_items',
                    'added' : 'yes'
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    if( response >= 2 ){
                        swal(
                            'You added all the items!',
                            'Proceed to checkout?',
                            'success'
                        );
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much for helping out!! It is very much appreciated.

Comment: @Giuls You are very welcome… it was not so complicated as [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50102637/checkout-distance-calculation-using-google-map-api-in-woocommerce-3-3/50433903#50433903)

Comment: The only thing is that the JS doesn't seem to trigger if multiple quantities of the same item is added to the cart. So it only counts 10xTshirts as 1xTshirt?

Comment: @Giuls Change `sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() )` to `WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count()` … and it will do the trick.

Comment: Spot on. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that there is currently a plug-in that provides a rest api for the cart.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/cart-rest-api-for-woocommerce/

with that plugin you can listen for item added event and get the item count

```
(function($) {
  $(document.body).on("added_to_cart", function() {
    $.get("/wp-json/wc/v2/cart/count-items", function(data) {
      console.log(data)
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```